# -intellij-idea- No character count for the output of a program

Tags: intellij-idea

The intellij IDE used to be able to show the character count of **highlighted output text in RUN tab** at bottom right corner, but recently it stop working. The character count on the editing area is still working. Can someone tell me how to fix it?

1.Run a program
2.Program output shows in the RUN tab
3.Highlighting the text in the Run tab
4.Character count not displayed at bottom right corner

Comment: Feel free to report issue on YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA